# Can an Electron/NW.js application be served in a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-webkit, nwjs

Given an [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) or [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) application, is there a way to run it on a remote server, and then access the application via a browser?

As an example, let's say I have stored a number of photos on a remote server.  Now I would like to view the photos in a photo viewing app written with Electron/NW.js.  Is there a way to launch the app on the server side, so that on my laptop I can just go to `http://server-ip:some-port` and use the app in the browser?

Comment: I tink that those technologies were specifically made to run nodejs apps locally

Comment: I'm highly confused what question aims for. Is this about running remote server serves asset and Electron access to it, or something else completely?

Comment: @OJKwon it's about running an Electron app on a remote server, and accessing the Electron app on another computer using a standard browser.

Answer (score 3):

> it's about running an Electron app on a remote server, and accessing the Electron app on another computer using a standard browser.

Electron / nw.js is nothing related to what you trying to achieve. Electron is framework allows to compose desktop application via javascript, and it is working as pretty much any other desktop application. If you'd like to access an application via browser on the remote server, that's territory for web page / application.